# Why is RequireJS ignoring my "paths" configuration?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

As-salamu-alikum

I have config as follows

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "assets/js/",
    paths: {
        "jq"        : "lib/jquery/jquery",
        "jqui"      : "lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4",
        "jl"        : "lib/jquery/jquery.jlayout",
        "jlb"       : "lib/jquery/jlayout.border",
        "jqs"       : "lib/jquery/jquery.sizes",
        "bb"        : "lib/marionette/backbone",
        "js2"       : "lib/json2/json2",
        "bbr"       : "lib/marionette/backbone.radio",
        "mt"        : "lib/marionette/backbone.marionette",
        "tk"        : "lib/marionette/marionette.toolkit",
        "us"        : "lib/underscore/underscore",
        "tpl"       : "lib/tpl/tpl"
    },
    waitSeconds: 20,
    shim: {
                "jqui":{
                        deps: ['jq']
                },
                "jl":{
                        deps: ['jq']
                },
                "jqs":{
                        deps: ['jq']
                },
                "jlb":{
                        deps: ['jq']
                },
        "us": {
            exports: "_"
        },
        "bb": {
            exports: ["Backbone"],
            deps: ['jq','us','js2']
        },
        "bbr":{
            exports: ["Radio"],
            deps: ["bb"]
        },
        "mt": {
            exports: "Marionette",
            deps: ["bb","bbr"]
        },
        "tk": {
            exports: "Toolkit",
            deps: ["mt"]
        }
    },
    deps: ['app/main']
});
```

app/main is as follows

```
define([
                "require",
                "jq",
                "jqui",
                "jqs",
                "jlb",
                "jl",
                "app/blogapp/bap"
                ], 
                function(
                        require,
                        $,
                        jLayout,
                        bap
                        ){  
                            'use strict';
                            jQuery(function($) {
                                var container = $('.layout');

                                function layout() {
                                    container.layout({
                                        resize: false,
                                        type: 'border',
                                        vgap: 8,
                                        hgap: 8
                                    });
                                };

                                $('.east').resizable({
                                    handles: 'w',
                                    stop: layout,
                                    resize: layout
                                });

                                $('.west').resizable({
                                    handles: 'e',
                                    stop: layout,
                                    resize: layout
                                });

                                $(window).resize(layout);

                                layout();
                                layout();
                            });
                            var BlogApp = require("app/blogapp/bap");
                            var blog = BlogApp.createApp();
                            blog.start(options);
                        },
                function(
                            err
                        ){
                            //The errback, error callback
                            //The error has a list of modules that failed
                            var failedId = err.requireModules && err.requireModules[0];

                            console.log("In err "+failedId);
                                console.log(err);
                        }
);
```

app/blogapp/bap is as follows

```
define(function (
                    require
                ){
                        var tk=require("tk");
                        var bb=require("bb");

                    var ba = tk.App.extend({
                        initialize: function() {},
                    });
                    return ba;
                },
        function(
                    err
                ){
                    //The errback, error callback
                    //The error has a list of modules that failed
                    var failedId = err.requireModules && err.requireModules[0];

                    console.log("In err "+failedId);
                        console.log(err);
                }
);
```

I am getting the following error

```
GET file:///C:/Users/Nadvi/Desktop/blog.org/assets/js/backbone.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
req.load @ require.js:2102
load @ require.js:1784
load @ require.js:900
fetch @ require.js:890
check @ require.js:922
enable @ require.js:1246
enable @ require.js:1644
(anonymous) @ require.js:1231
(anonymous) @ require.js:136
each @ require.js:61
enable @ require.js:1183
init @ require.js:851
callGetModule @ require.js:1273
completeLoad @ require.js:1677
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1823
require.js:388 function hasPathFallback(backbone)
require.js:170 Uncaught Error: Script error for "backbone", needed by: bbr
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:170)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1844)
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: tk,mt
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
    at makeError (require.js:170)
    at checkLoaded (require.js:743)
    at require.js:769
makeError @ require.js:170
checkLoaded @ require.js:743
(anonymous) @ require.js:769
setTimeout (async)
checkLoaded @ require.js:767
(anonymous) @ require.js:769
setTimeout (async)
checkLoaded @ require.js:767
(anonymous) @ require.js:769
setTimeout (async)
checkLoaded @ require.js:767
(anonymous) @ require.js:769
setTimeout (async)
checkLoaded @ require.js:767
(anonymous) @ require.js:769
```

What is going wrong here I can not understand how backbone.js path is going wrong.Please help me.

Zazakallah khair

Nadvi

Comment: `exports: ["Backbone"]` - that's an odd syntax, shouldn't it be: `exports: "Backbone"`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the libraries you are using and check whether they register themselves as AMD modules. The code for this typically looks like this:

```
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
      // Export global even in AMD case in case this script is loaded with
      // others that may still expect a global Backbone.
      root.Backbone = factory(root, exports, _, $);
    });
```

The one I have here is taken from Backbone. You see there that Backbone depends on the modules `underscore`, `jquery`, and `exports`. The `exports` module is one of the 3 internal modules provided internally by RequireJS. The other two internal modules are `require` and `module`. You don't need to do anything special for these internal modules: they are always available. However, RequireJS needs to be able to find modules named `underscore` and `jquery`. This is where you run into trouble. The error you get is because `backbone.radio`, which also calls `define`, depends on `backbone`. However, there is no module named `backbone` available anywhere in your configuration. What you do have is `bb` but `"bb" !== "backbone"` so RequireJS does not see it in the configuration and assumes it can be loaded from `baseUrl` and that fails.

There's an additional problem that some modules, jQuery being the most prominent example, call `define` with a hardcoded module name, like this:

```
define( "jquery", [], function() {
```

The first argument is the module name. Most of the time `define` is called with the list of dependencies as the first argument, and the module name is inferred. However, passing a string as the first argument hardcodes the module name. If you run into `define` calls like this, *you must refer to the module by that hardcoded name*. You cannot just put `jq` in your `paths` and point it to the jQuery file. When RequireJS loads `jq` it will find a module named `jquery` and will complain that they don't match.

My recommendations are:

1. Inspect everything you are loading and check the `define` calls as I explained above.
2. In your `paths` configuration put the *usual* names under which these libraries are named: `jquery, backbone, underscore` rather than the abbreviations.
3. Remove all `shim` configurations for modules that call `define`. `shim` is only for code that does not call `define`. Using `shim` for a module that calls `define` leads to undefined behavior. (At best it will be ignored.)
4. You can set a `map` configuration that will allow you to use abbreviations in your own code if you want. The `map` perform a module name substitution. For instance, in the example below, whenever the module named `jq` is required, `jquery` is loaded instead. The asterisk means that the substitutions are good everywhere.

Your configuration should look like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "assets/js/",
    paths: {
        "jquery"          : "lib/jquery/jquery",
        // ...
        "backbone"        : "lib/marionette/backbone",
        "backbone.radio"  : "lib/marionette/backbone.radio",
        "marionette"      : "lib/marionette/backbone.marionette",
        // ...
    },
    map: {
      "*": {
        jq:  "jquery",
        bb:  "backbone",
        bbr: "backbone.radio",
        mt:  "marionette" 
      }
    },
    shim: {
      // whatever shims are appropriate
    }
});
```

Comment: Zazakallah khair Louis I am going to do so .

Comment: Zazakallah khair all of you for helping me.Now my config.js has became the following

Comment: Zazakallah khair to all of you for helping me . but I get the following error Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.sizes.js:77
(anonymous) @ jquery.sizes.js:77
jquery.jlayout.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.jlayout.js:9
(anonymous) @ jquery.jlayout.js:9
What should I do? Please help me.  
 
Zazakallah khair again for reading.Nadvi